# How to build, submit, and add a macOS version to an iOS app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, provisioning-profile

Assume the there is an iOS/iPad app already in Apple's App Store; and it turns out that a working macOS/Mac (10.15 or later) app can be built from the same project, with no code changes, by simply checking the Mac (Catalyst) checkbox in the Xcode (11.4 or later) project.

What is the proper sequence of setting the correct bundle ID for the Mac app, getting any new provisioning profiles (if needed), adding anything else required to the Xcode project (Credits?), adding to the iTunes Connect record for the app (description, screen shots?), etc., that is required to successfully upload the Mac app archive to the App Store, so that customers who download or buy the iOS app can get the Mac (Catalyst) version as well?

Are there any features or functions that need to be added or removed from an previously approved iOS app to prevent the macOS version from being immediately rejected for being unsuitable as a Mac app? (and not including any reasons that might cause a new build of the iOS app to be rejected as well.)